# Selecting specific elements of a list satisfying some criteria

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of 1000 sublists and each sublist is length 400. I'd like to produce a new set containing only those sublists where element 25, 75 and 250 satisfy some criteria. 
The following works on sublists of length 3 with some toy criteria:

`Cases[set, {a_, b_, c_} /; 1 < a < 5 && 0 < b < 4 && 4 < c < 8]`, where `set` is the list of 1000 sublists.

How may I construct a list similar to `{a_,b_,c_}` but that is instead 400 elements? That is I want to produce a list like `{a1_,a2_,a3_,....,a400_}`. Probably it's simple but I've been playing about with array and Append etc. and not found a way.

Comment: Better use `Select` with the selecting funtion that directly accesses the values of the sublist.

Comment: @HenrikSchumcher Yes, but if possible I would like to create this list of 400 elements in any case.

Answer (score 8):

> Yes, but if possible I would like to create this list of 400 elements
>   in any case.

No, you quite likely do not want to construct this list. You should rather use something like the following:

```
set = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {1000, 400}];
result1 = Select[
     set, 
     1 < #[[25]] < 5 && 0 < #[[75]] < 4 && 4 < #[[250]] < 8 &
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0019

Alternatively, one can do something like

```
result2 = Pick[
     set, 
     1 < #25 < 5 && 0 < #75 < 4 && 4 < #250 < 8 & @@@ set
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.032

However, I do not recommend it, because, as you can see, it is super slow. However, `Pick` is really fast, if used with vectorized code:

```
result3 = Pick[
     set,
     Times[
      UnitStep[# - 1.] UnitStep[Subtract[5., #]] &[set[[All, 25]]],
      UnitStep[# - 0.] UnitStep[Subtract[4., #]] &[set[[All, 75]]],
      UnitStep[# - 4.] UnitStep[Subtract[8., #]] &[set[[All, 250]]]
      ],
     1
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0000686

Of course, all results are equal:

```
result1 == result2 == result3
```

> True

Comment: Thank you very much. This works for me.  Just out of interest, is it possible to create such a list? Say if one needed to define a function of an arbitrary number of variables, `f[a_,b_,c_,...]` etc.. then construction of such a list might be useful.

Comment: Well, "pure" functions constructed with `&` have actually an arbitrary number of arguments...